# Get started with CNTK in Python via Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, cntk

I've installed CNTK version 2,5 in Anaconda 3, python 3.6. But when I run Microsoft CNTK-sample codes in Spyder, the python crashed (Kernel died, restarting) and I got this error when I debugged the code line by line;
 NameError: "name 'cntk' is not defined" 
Could you please tell me what's wrong? Did I miss sths to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, [Show us your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can reproduce, or analyse what is wrong :)

Comment: Does CNTK show if you do 'pip list'?

Comment: yes, that shows

Comment: Did you install CNTK from the wheel file? If so, try uninstalling that and just do `pip install cntk` since it was recently put on PyPI. That's how I have it and it runs in Spyder.

Comment: Thanks for your description.

Comment: Just curious, did that get it to work?